# Server Sent Events Error : 406 (Not Acceptable) in Angular5 + Spring App

Tags: spring, angular5, observable, server-sent-events, eventsource

I am working with Angular5 application , where i need to show Real-time data on dashboard.our backend is written in spring(v4.x) which having api which sends results when any server event is generated.

But when i am calling this api in Angular app which always gives me

> GET
>   http://192.168.1.9:8080/proxta/api/student-answered-correctly-by-que_nft
>   406 (Not Acceptable)

**Response Header (Copied from network)**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.9:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization, Link, X-Total-Count
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 22 Oct 2018 09:50:59 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

**Request Header**

```
GET /proxta/api/student-answered-correctly-by-que_nft HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.9:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://192.168.1.9:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://192.168.1.9:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInNjb3BlIjpbIm9wZW5pZCJdLCJleHAiOjE1NDAyMDI3MTIsImlhdCI6MTU0MDIwMDkxMiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiJhMjU2N2FjNS01ZjhjLTQ3OGUtOGI3NS1lMTI1NzFlMTQ0N2QiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ3ZWJfYXBwIn0.I5UOoVxrrJwa140FRJDSIxuSeySMnHdHJv8rIBPZmGi-jyobKbea7AjZ6dqwblPx3mMXnAqPlp8XxTeDRvRe9BEgHzRxvOmz5Pp3IC1RetLdwjcmM2qKCcUlagkita3GwEpsOCfLWIaCXBufLycmpu1-96gUF-FLqFvYPQnNfK_JZkrGesu33UUKDkEj_PbC8kxK2toLh8PNo7IJ16uhKLdZi7i9oqx2QBCMtYc9uqiPpv-NTbhUZfYnoigG8Tphcr6GtfQJ53eK4NBFStIOpAJ-b6LSixbaCA1W7_x2QHJ-gxp-iscGgXcdouDlXaKMtE-D6IfDzPwQE7MoeAhKsA; session_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInNjb3BlIjpbIm9wZW5pZCJdLCJhdGkiOiJhMjU2N2FjNS01ZjhjLTQ3OGUtOGI3NS1lMTI1NzFlMTQ0N2QiLCJleHAiOjE1NDA4MDU3MTIsImlhdCI6MTU0MDIwMDkxMiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiIsIlJPTEVfVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiI3NDBjMDAxOC1mNmEwLTQ5NzUtYjg4OS0yMzUxNGI5ZGIwOTEiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ3ZWJfYXBwIn0.ZE8NLJIie45Ibh6dn1tlpwOmLuf5Lw-ER75cdzNsMDCpy6CPRSIIkBr0gaUJEvLlKQgqOS_LsD5cJ3ugdjYBugN4ye3s3uIccDhn3b0y5Ek1NNPyZSK0b7wWSDIhhdgmCVAmBN5ZKAWr5iNmMzSMpww34ahv8XQ8Q1zJNUUxVrdcXL20PEnEQvSP1fnh8vhzheJGNN7PXPSS2LMOmY515yhIAT8psNluOpOQ38g86IQy-p8CWnUZsNjhfXIxo6Zu9Y9T_witSKuDIeIQ7wAfB_gExPOSIDHaW5XFjSqDfpHIFizBLiXdDDpnAKvNEIHsojMVbP9Z0hRDYFOcQxQ7qg
```

**Angular Side Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin-dashboard-content',
    templateUrl: './admin-dashboard-content.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./admin-dashboard-content.component.css']
})

export class AdminDashboardContentComponent implements OnInit {
    myData: any;
    constructor(private admiDashboardServiceMain: admiDashboardServiceMain,
        private zone: NgZone) {
        this.connect();
    }
    ngOnInit() { }
    connect(): void {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'accept': 'text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
        let source = new EventSource('http://192.168.1.9:8080/proxta/api/student-answered-correctly-by-que_nft', options)
        source.addEventListener('message', message => {
            console.log(message)
        });
    }
}
```

- i am just console output for now . help appreciated , thanks

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a POST endpoint?

Comment: No @Stefan its a GET @GetMapping(path = "/api/student-answered-correctly-by-que_nft", produces = "text/event-stream")

Answer (score 2):

When Angular (version 10) sends request for EventSource, uses the Request header: Accept: text/event-stream.

If your server can not produce this type of output, the server will refuse the request. With spring boot, the request will not even reach your controller code.

See my (bad) Spring boot code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/flux/{api}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Movie> getMovieFlux(
        @PathVariable String api, @RequestParam("title") String title) {
    return service.getMovieFlux(title, api);
}
```

I only needed to change the "produce" part of it:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/flux/{api}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Movie> getMovieFlux(
        @PathVariable String api, @RequestParam("title") String title) {
    return service.getMovieFlux(title, api);
}
```

Or the same with ServerSentEvent:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/flux/{api}")
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<Movie>> getMovieFlux(
        @PathVariable String api, @RequestParam("title") String title) {
    return service.getMovieFlux(title, api)
            .map(movie -> ServerSentEvent.<Movie>builder().build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the EventSource API allows for sending HTTP headers. Try just creating a new event source object like this:

```
let source = new EventSource('http://192.168.1.9:8080/proxta/api/student-answered-correctly-by-que_nft', {withCredentials: true});
```

Comment: Thanks @cearserg's I tried that it's sents same response 406

Comment: Hmm what browser are you using? Also take a look at this thread, seems that they had the same issue you did https://community.openhab.org/t/sse-over-rest-api/19220/5

Comment: i am tested this with google chrome and mozilla  having same issue

Comment: This may be an issue on the server side.

Comment: yeah i am trying to figure out , this is because server sending response which is not acceptable by browser